# Exchange 2013 : EAC, OWA Error: we can't get that information right now

Tags: email, upgrade, exchange

I am trying to upgrade my (small, ie 50 mailboxes) existing environment (Exchange 2010 SP3 running on Win28k, two DCs) to Exchange 2013.

So I fired up a brand new Windows Server 2012R2, installed Exchange 2013, installed CU8. (new Hostname, IP etc)

The console is working fine. But when I try to connect to the eac (https://HOSTNAME/OWA) or ECP I getting this message: (Note I try to login with my Administrator or user credentials).

> :-( something went wrong Sorry, we can't get that information right
>   now. Please try again later. If the problem continues, contact your
>   helpdesk

Thats it. No event-log entrys etc.

Checked also the bindings of IIS. Removed the 127.0.0.1 bindings. Didnt helped me.

What is wrong? I also tried reinstalling the new Server. Same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue occured just with "old" mailboxes that had still a "move-request"-flag. Removing it with "remove-moverequest" worked out.